# How to exclude C/C++ system headers when SublimeClang parses?

Tags: c++, c, sublimetext2, clang

I'm using sublime text 2 to develop a tiny operating system (C and assembly based), and I must not use any C++ features. For example, I need to implement the 'stdio.h' myself, and need to define 'bool' too. But SublimeClang always tells me

> Error - redeclaration of C++ built-in type 'bool'

When I write

```
typedef int bool;
```

And it will include the system's 'stdio.h' instead of mine.

Also, when building the project, the compiler options are like:

> i386-elf-gcc -Ikern/init/ -fno-builtin -Wall -ggdb -m32 -gstabs -nostdinc  -fno-stack-protector -Ilibs/ -Ikern/debug/ -Ikern/driver/ -Ikern/trap/ -Ikern/mm/ -Ikern/libs/ -Ikern/sync/ -c kern/init/entry.S -o obj/kern/init/entry.o
>
> i386-elf-ld -m    elf_i386 -nostdlib -T tools/kernel.ld -o bin/kernel  obj/kern/init/entry.o obj/kern/init/init.o obj/kern/libs/readline.o obj/kern/libs/stdio.o obj/kern/debug/kdebug.o obj/kern/debug/kmonitor.o obj/kern/debug/panic.o obj/kern/driver/clock.o obj/kern/driver/console.o obj/kern/driver/intr.o obj/kern/driver/picirq.o obj/kern/trap/trap.o obj/kern/trap/trapentry.o obj/kern/trap/vectors.o obj/kern/mm/default_pmm.o obj/kern/mm/pmm.o  obj/libs/printfmt.o obj/libs/string.o
>
> i386-elf-ld -m    elf_i386 -nostdlib -N -T tools/boot.ld obj/boot/bootasm.o obj/boot/bootmain.o -o obj/bootblock.o

So, how to use the most basic C functions when SublimeClang parses? I cannot google out any useful configuration file of SublimeClang that helps.

Comment: Could you not name your header something other than `stdio.h`?

Comment: Yes, but I just want to stop clang including system headers. It causes trouble.